# Function to query by custom field and category

Tags: customization

A function was written for our small non-profit org by a developer who is no longer available. The function works well, and we now need a similar function as a modification of the query criteria.

This function returns a list of links that are filtered by two variables:

1. Filtered by the author of the current page – so that the links provided are only pages authored by the same author.
2. The second filter is by category

The result is a list of links to pages within the category which were authored by the same author.

```
function team_resources_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;

    $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 
        'author' => $authordata->ID, 
        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 
        'category_name' => 'team-resources' 
    ) );

    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . 
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) .            
            '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

We need a similar function that filters by custom field key instead of Author. The second criteria – “category” would remain unchanged.

Example: If the key on the current page for the custom field “Project ID” is “Project 1″, the function will return a list of pages which:

1. Have key “Project1″
2. Are associated with the category as in the original script.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just make sure that meta key is `Project ID`.

```
function projects_posts() {
    global $post;

    $project_posts = get_posts( array( 

        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 
        'category_name' => 'team-resources',
        'meta_key' => 'Project ID', 
        'meta_value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Project ID', 1 ) 
    ) );

    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $project_posts as $project_post ) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $project_post->ID ) . '">' . 
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $project_post->post_title, $project_post->ID ) .            
            '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. It was very generous of you. You're a 10 in my book...I'm new to the site and will figure out how to add a 10 to your reputation list. Thanks again!

Comment: No Problem. Accept the answer and vote up please. We are here to help! :)

Comment: Ooops I didn't describe the need properly. 

I don't want to enter "1" in the function.

I want to enter "Project ID" in the function, then have the script look at the "Project ID" field on the current page. When it sees a "1" it then looks for all the other pages with a "1" which have the same category and list those pages. 

The original script looks for the author of the page, and pulls up all the other pages in that category authored by the same author. 

Instead of Author I'd like it to look for that value of "Project ID" and pull up pages with similar value.

Comment: Sorry you are very kind. I'm lame with the commenting system. I probably blew it a little in the description. Can you help me dial it in?     Thanks so much!

Comment: I'll try to restate in hopes I can dial in the function:
What I'd like the function to do:

1. Ask - What value has been assigned on the page for "Project ID" (the value set by me when I created the page).

2. Give a list of all the pages which also have that value, and also match the category criteria.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Wh

Comment: @WarmHeart What did you mean `I don't want to enter "1" in the function.`

Comment: My error. There must have been another function in my theme's functions with projects posts as it I kept crashing wordpress with my mistakes.      I was able to modify the script a bit but can't get it working.    My script is here       http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177168/php-custom-query-function-assistance      I'd be very grateful for followup.  You've been very helpful.