# Php custom query function assistance

Tags: customization

I'd like the script to return a list of posts which are in the category 'team-resources' and also have the custom field value for Hub ID which the script finds on the page.

If the page carries a value for "Hub ID" of Hub1, the script would return a list of all pages with custom value Hub1 which are also in the category 'team-resources'

If the script runs on a page that has a value of Hub2 in custom field, it would return a list of all pages with Hub2 which are also in the cateogry 'team-resources'.

Many thanks to iambriansreed who helped me get this far and was very helpful. It was my error that keeps me coming back.

Any help much appreciated,
wh

```
function hubs_resources_posts() {
    global $post;

    $hub_resources_posts = get_posts( array( 

        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 
        'category_name' => 'team-resources',
        'meta_key' => 'Hub ID', 
        'meta_value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Hub ID', 1 ) 
    ) );

    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $hub_resources_posts as $hub_resources_post ) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $hub_resources_post->ID ) . '">' . 
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $hub_resources_post->post_title, $hub_resources_post->ID ) .            
            '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? How is it not working?

Comment: I created a field "Hub ID" and put Hub1 as a value. I created several similar pages in the category 'team-resources' but they don't show up on a list of links. I assume I must have mis-adapted the code generously offered by iambriansreed.    I played with it for some time but unable to get the proper result. If the code looks perfect I'll try some more.  Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure the actual meta_key isn't `Hub ID` but something like `Hub_ID` or something like that.